# Is there a way to save the current time of the countdown timer?

Tags: python

I want to build a program that counting down from 25 to 0.
I want to make a way to save the current time if the program crashes or if the user exit the program.. etc.

Is this possible to do that, I can't guess when the program ended.

So I want to save the current time into a file, and then read from the file, and then start the timer from where it stopped.

```
from time import sleep

def countdown():
    time = 25
    while time > 0:
        print(time)
        sleep(1)
        time -= 1
        # if his program crashes, how can I save the current time ?

countdown()
```

Comment: @EdWard There's an if question, please check

Comment: you can use `try/except` to catch some errors and save data but if it is real crash then probably nothing can help.

Comment: Save the end time somewhere, and use the difference between the current time and the end time for displaying the timer. Use a clock from the `time` module for this instead of trying to make your own clock using `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Use e.g. sqlite to store all the times (and logs I suppose) to be able to retrieve it in a structured format, or if you don't care about structure you can simply write them down into a plain text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a file to save the timers time, for example:

```
from time import sleep

def countdown(time=25):
    while time > 0:
        print(time)
        sleep(1)
        time -= 1
        # if his program crashes, how can I save the current time ?
        f = open("last_time.txt", "a")
        f.write(str(time))
        f.close()

# next time app opens you can read the file to know if there was a stopped timer
f = open("last_time.txt", "r")
if f.read():
    time = int(f.read()) 
    countdown(time)
else:
    countdown()
```

Comment: Wait, How can I keep run the timer when the program ends ? I want it to keep move also when the program is not running.

Comment: with this design of program you can't, when program is not running you have to run it again. with the method I said you only can resume the previous counting.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your `countdown()` method into a class and then use pickle

```
# coding=utf-8
import os, pickle, time

SAVE_FILE = "saved_countdown.dat"

class Countdown(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        """
        :param t: time to wait in seconds, float or int
        """
        self.t = t

    def run(self):
        while self.t > 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.t -= 1
            print("\rRemaining:", self.t, end="")
        time.sleep(self.t)
        self.t = 0
        print("\nCountdown finished.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(SAVE_FILE):
            with open(SAVE_FILE, "rb") as f:
                cd = pickle.load(f)
            print("Restored Countdown from file")
            os.remove(SAVE_FILE)
        else:
            cd = Countdown(25)
            print("No save file found, created new countdown")
        cd.run()
    except:
        if cd.t > 0:
            with open(SAVE_FILE, "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(cd, f)
            print("Program crashed, saved backup file")
```

It should be pretty self.explanatory with all the prints

More about try/except: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

More about pickle: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pickle-python-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can write out the content of the timer each time you've decremented it, then load the value from the file if present when starting up (if the file is present).

I'm using JSON here since it's an easy to understand format for humans as well (you can also use the `pickle` module to serialize python data). The `with` statements makes sure the file is closed appropriately after being read from or written to.

After running through the file we clean up by unlinking (removing) the state file:

```python
from time import sleep
import os
import os.path
import json

def countdown(persist_file=None):
    time = 25
    fp = None

    if persist_file and os.path.exists(persist_file):
        with open(persist_file, 'rb') as f:
            time = json.load(f)['previous_time']

    while time > 0:
        print(time)
        sleep(1)
        time -= 1
        # if his program crashes, how can I save the current time ?

        if persist_file:
            with open(persist_file, 'wb') as f:
                json.dump({'previous_time': time}, f)

    if persist_file:
        os.unlink(persist_file)

countdown(persist_file='test.persist')
```

You can extend the set of values being persisted by adding more keys to the dictionary and their included values (or persisting the state of the application by having the relevant data in a dictionary that you serialize and deserialize as needed).

This can also be optimized to avoid re-opening the file each time and made more resilient to failure by serializing to a temporary file and then renameing it over the old state file instead of writing directly to the state file. However, to understand the general concept, this will hopefully be enough.

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: That seems to indicate that you for some reason have an empty file around from a failed attempt at writing it.